# Drupal Multilingual Home page

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am having a problem with multilingual settings. Here is my site URL http://centriumcapital.com/centrium. Everything is working fine but I just want when someone requests http://centriumcapital.com/centrium the default language should be French and also content of the home page also should in French.

I added code in settings.php file to make French language as default language it selects the French language as default but content is still from English language.

Comment: are you using Locale module ?

Comment: Internationalization and some other modules

Comment: My website is complete except this issue. if i use locale module what should effect on my rest of site/work which is almost completed

Comment: It will not affect other parts of site, but be aware and don't do it directly on live site. Do it on localhost. check whether it satisfies your usecase or not, and then upload the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the problem. in the languages setting Browser default language was enabled. so i just unchecked browser language and it is working fine now.

Thanks to mohit_rocks

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/setting-basics-drupal-multilingual-site-languages-ui-translation) Page. You can set this using locale module and [i18n translation](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module.

Comment: My website is complete except this issue. if i use locale module what should effect on my rest of site/work which is almost completed

Comment: It will not affect other parts of site, but be aware and don't do it directly on live site. Do it on localhost. check whether it satisfies your usecase or not, and then upload the site

Comment: but i am already using locale and i18n translation modules. and everything (translation of blocks , pages and string) is working fine but i can't set French front page as my site default home page http://centriumcapital.com/centrium where centrium is directory at server that contains my development project.

Comment: Can't you set site's front page as this url http://centriumcapital.com/centrium/fr , if it is not creating a interrupt with other features

Comment: thanks for your help. Problem was in Browser default language. i unchecked this from Configuration->Regional & Language->Languages.